# Porque me la terminal me arroja muchos errores con el codigo?

Tags: python

Tengo un proyecto que entregar, en el cual tengo que ser capaz de elegir la variable por la cual quiero que se ordenen mis listas, además tengo que hacer que en el resultado me arroje el "creador" junto con los likes o comentarios ordenados conforme al input.
Todo funciona bien pero todos los problemas empiezan por el input
Este es mi codigo:

```
creadores = ("pepe", "joaquin", "pique", "bebesitoemoxito", "werever", "ariel")
likes = (3, 2, 6, 7, 1, 2)
comentarios = (9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4)

def bubble_sort(array):
   array = list(array)
   longitud = len(array)
   for i in range(0, longitud - 1):
        isSwap = False
        for j in range(0, longitud - i - 1):
            if array[j][0] < array[j + 1][0]:
                array[j], array[j + 1] = array[j + 1], array[j]
                isSwap = True
        if not isSwap:
           break
        return tuple(array)

orden = input("¿Con qué variable deseas ordenar? (likes/comentarios): ").strip()
if orden == "likes":
     sorted_data = bubble_sort(zip(likes, creadores, comentarios))
     for like, creador, comentario in sorted_data:
         print(f"Likes: {like}, Creador: {creador}, Comentario: {comentario}")
elif orden == "comentarios":
    sorted_data = bubble_sort(zip(comentarios, creadores, likes))
    for comentario, creador, like in sorted_data:
         print(f"Comentario: {comentario}, Creador: {creador}, Likes: {like}")
else:
    print("Entrada inválida. Debe ser 'likes' o 'comentarios'.")'
```

Comment: ¿Seguro que es así? Creo que le diste demasiada sangría a `return tuple`. Además, a qué errores te refieres? Puedes indicarnos cuáles son? Por cierto, el `'` al final del código no va.

Comment: Como comenta Mateo el código es correcto, los dos problemas que presenta yo los considero más errores tipográficos que otra cosa;  esa camilla final que sobra y  el `return` al que le sobra un nivel de sangrado (o mejor aun, substituir el `break` por el `return` directamente). Quitando lo de la comilla el código no debe generar ningún error (más allá de avisos del linter si es que usas uno), simplemente no ordena bien al romper el ciclo antes de tiempo.

Comment: Además, el sangrado es algo caótico, tienes niveles identados con tres espacios, otros con cuatro, otros con cinco... te aconsejo usar siempre la misma cantidad de espacios por nivel de sangrado  en todo el script, cuatro por convención, pero si usas otro numero al menos que sea así en todo el código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes el `return` dentro de un `for`. En la primera iteración, retornas.

La solución es mover el `return` fuera del `for`, para ejecutarlo cuando ya se haya ordenado todo.

Solución:

```
def bubble_sort(array):
    array = list(array)
    longitud = len(array)
    for i in range(0, longitud - 1):
        isSwap = False
        for j in range(0, longitud - i - 1):
            if array[j][0] < array[j + 1][0]:
                array[j], array[j + 1] = array[j + 1], array[j]
                isSwap = True
        if not isSwap:
            break
    return tuple(array)
```

produce:

```
¿Con qué variable deseas ordenar? (likes/comentarios): likes
Likes: 7, Creador: bebesitoemoxito, Comentario: 6
Likes: 6, Creador: pique, Comentario: 7
Likes: 3, Creador: pepe, Comentario: 9
Likes: 2, Creador: joaquin, Comentario: 8
Likes: 2, Creador: ariel, Comentario: 4
Likes: 1, Creador: werever, Comentario: 5

Process finished with exit code 0
```